liquibase: Синтаксическая ошибка в выражении SQL. Как описать поле для хранения массива строк?
есть такой скрипт для описания сущности
create table order_request
(
    id                      SERIAL                          not null primary key,
    transaction_id          uuid                            not null,
    errors                  text                            null,
    CONSTRAINT order_request_fk FOREIGN KEY (transaction_id) REFERENCES transactions (id)
);

он выполняется успешно.
но если я меняю errors на хранение массива вот так
create table order_request
(
    id                      SERIAL                          not null primary key,
    transaction_id          uuid                            not null,
    errors                  text[]                          null,
    CONSTRAINT order_request_fk FOREIGN KEY (transaction_id) REFERENCES transactions (id)
);

то build отдает
liquibase: Синтаксическая ошибка в выражении SQL

"если я меняю...", то что?

дополнил liquibase: Синтаксическая ошибка в выражении SQL

Со стороны PostgreSQL тут не должно быть возражений. Так что все претензии к препарсеру/чекеру Liquidbase... может, он тупо настраиваемый или даже отключаемый?
